# Is exposing sins committed while he was young (unaccountable) haram?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

Exposing one's sin is a very serious sin because of this Hadith:

> Abu Hurayrah said: I heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say: “All of my ummah will be forgiven except those who sin openly. It is a part of sinning openly when a man does something at night, then the following morning when Allaah has concealed his sin, he says, ‘O So and so, I did such and such last night,’ when all night his Lord has concealed him and the next morning he uncovers what Allaah had concealed.”
>
> *(Narrated by [al-Bukhaari, 6069](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/99)).*

But what about if an adult exposed the sins he committed when he was very young, that is when he was not accountable for his sins (because of [the Hadith](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/17/1) that says the pen is lifted from three people: a child until he reaches puberty; an insane man until he comes to his senses; one who is asleep until he wakes up.).

For example, an adult says "I lied to my mother when I was 9 years old." Is this haram?

Comment: The same principle of concealing sins still applies, whether you did the sin as a child or adult. Just because sins before puberty are forgiven does not mean you have the right to tell others about them. Conceal those as well.